# Как сделать на PHP, чтобы пользователь не входил каждый раз в чате?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**Как сделать на PHP, чтобы пользователь не входил каждый раз в чате?** Что-то на подобии localstorage в JS. Чтобы человек зарегистрировался и чат его запомнил, чтобы в дальнейшем пользователю при входе в чат не входить каждый раз по новой.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

на PHP можно посмотреть в сторону $_SESSION или $_COOKIE.
После авторизации пользователя сохраняйте его идентификатор в сессию, а затем проверяйте авторизировался ли пользователь.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам)